# php parent constructor in Exception Class

Tags: php, exception, parent, construct

So I was reading the PHP manual again and saw a comment on the code of a custom exception to call the parent Exception constructor and do not understand the purpose of this.

Here is the code:

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
        // Redefine the exception so message isn't optional
        public function __construct($message, $code = 0) {
        // some code

        // make sure everything is assigned properly
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }

    // custom string representation of object
    public function __toString() {
    return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }

    public function customFunction() {
        echo "A custom function for this type of exception\n";
    }
}
```

I don't understand the logic of:

```
//make sure everything is assigned properly
parent::__construct($message, $code);
```

Any logic as to why this is done would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Exception class contains own properties such as `$code` and `$message`

They are ihnerited by child classes, example:

```
class Exception {
  protected $code ;
  protected $message ;

  public function __construct($code, $message){
    $this->code = $code ;
    $this->message = $message ;

    //AND some important default actions are performed
    //when class is instantiated.
  }
}
```

So, after you called `parent::__construct()`

Your child class will have instance variables `$code` and `$message` set properly.

```
$myEx = new MyException("10", "DB Error") ;
//Now you can get the error code, because it was set in its parent constructor:
$code = $myEx->getCode() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP will not call the parent's constructor method automatically when you override the constructor method. So if the parent's constructor is still necessary, you have to call it manually.

Answer (score 0):

well the base Exception class of PHP assignes the message / code to some internal properties.
i'm sure the author of this class could have not written the _*construct(); but in this case he wanted to demonstrate that parent::*_construct(); has to be called if you overwrite the constructor.